# ASP.Net Inproc session restarted after markup change in VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-8, iis-7.5, visual-studio-2012

I upgraded my development machine to Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012.

I'm testing my ASP.Net applications (also upgraded to .net 4.5) on a local IIS.

One thing that is annoying me, that hasn't been this way with my last configuration (Windows 7, VS 2010, .net 4.0), is that InProc-sessions are being restarted after changes in markup files.

Example: I'm logged into my local ASP.net application, make and save changes in a *.ascx file, refresh my webbrowser and the session is gone.

How do I turn off the session restart issue?

**Edit**:
I tried to repro the issue with the new VS 2012 Web Application project template, removed unnecessary content and couldn't repro this issue.

However, in my real project the issue still remains: Changes to an aspx or ascx file result in the Application_Start event being fired.

I also stripped down the web.config in my real project to the bare minimum to look like the one in the new project, but that didn't allow me to remove the bug either. Things I commented out in the web.config were DevExpress Controls, custom healthMonitoring, IIS UrlRewrite 2

Applicationpool as Integrated, v4.0 with NetworkService as Identity

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/p/1457959/3344056.aspx and http://forums.asp.net/t/1821704.aspx/1?Asp+net+Session+Problem

Comment: @m.qayyum: What do you want to tell me with that links?

Comment: Can you please provide small code which can reproduce this issue and email it to "netfx45compat(at)Microsoft(dot)com"?

Comment: Can you please check if this is same issue as of connect bug? http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766223/application-start-firing-multiple-times-when-saving-ascx-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: @Anand, that's a broken link.

Comment: this is not broken link, you need to sign up for VS feedback and then it will snow up contents. check http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/c5913a60-f23f-48a9-a98c-858bec34df51/

Comment: @Anand: I tried to repro, but failed. I edited my question, please have a look. I think my issue is related to the one you linked, but not the same. I've never experienced the Application_Start event being fired multiple times for the same request.

Comment: I see. So removing either of these "DevExpress Controls, custom healthMonitoring, IIS UrlRewrite 2" fixes the issue?can you pin point which one causes the issue by commenting/uncommenting one of these controls? this will help us isolating the issue and possiblely finding out the root cause.

Comment: @Anand: No, removing any of "DevExpress Controls, custom healthMonitoring, IIS UrlRewrite 2" didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: @Anand: Anything new on this issue?

Comment: @citronas: can you add this app setting in web.config file and try this scenario and see whether issue repros?             <appSettings>
    <add key ="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled"></add>
  </appSettings>

Comment: @Anand:Yes thanks, using this setting fixes my problem

Comment: @citronas: Many thanks for confirming and adding this workaround as an answer. It took some time to find root cause for this behavior. Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not going to try to take the credit for this but the answer is buried in the 11th comment on the original question by @[Anand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1615515/anand):

Add this key in web.config:

```
<appSettings><add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" /></appSettings>
```

and the problem goes away. VS becomes far more responsive too. Only downside is you lose the server-side trickery from Page Inspector.

Hopefully MS will provide a fix soon..

Comment: Adding this key actually fixes the issue. I also hope that MS fixes this workaround soon and that other developers with the same issue can benefit from Anand's answer.

Comment: I'm curious, did you run into the same issue?

Comment: Yes - been pulling my hair out for a couple of weeks! The worst part is it messes up VS2010 on the same machine too, I guess because of the hooks that get installed into IIS.

Comment: Yes. We are actively working on this issue to fix it properly. Fix will be available in future update of VS 2012.

Comment: @Anand Anything else that might cause this problem?  I'm experiencing the same thing in vs2013 on a project converted from vs2010.  Additionally, the project probably went from .NET 1.1 to .NET 3.5.  I tried the app setting above but it didn't help my situation.  Weird thing is that it only happens on some projects.  I have several projects that took same migration path that I am able to make markup changes fine.

Comment: @Terry, Page inspector should not interfere with .net 3.5 projects. here are prereq of page inspector [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28web.pageinspector%29;k%28VS.SolutionExplorer.Selection%29;k%28VS.SolutionExplorer%29;k%28VS.SolutionExplorer.Solutions%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29&rd=true).  Can you check your web.config file and see target framework? we fixed this issue in recent updates of vs2013. There can be other components in the pipe line causing session restart.

Comment: @Anand What am I looking for in web.config?  I can't find 'target' or 'framework'.  Under the website properties, it says Target framework: 3.5.  I checked another project that (to my knowledge) went through same flow (conversion)...and I *am* able to modify markup without killing session.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Terry, this issue you are mentioning is unrelated to Page Inspector.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is your application is doing a dynamic compile which means any changes to the markup files will cause the application to restart. Any application restart, as you know, will dump the InProc session.

A "Web Application" on your local template is set differently so it isn't restarting the whole application. There are advantages to having precompilation though.

There's a couple of ways around this.

**Why this is happening**

ASP.NET 4.5 allows you to run "web pages" side by side with "web applications" by default. This is likely what's causing changes to an aspx to fire a precomilation (which "web pages" have to do every time there is a change).
More info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx

There is also quite a few changes to optimise the web server in the new version. You can see details of those changes here and they also can explain the change when you upgrade.
http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet/whats-new

The solution is still the same regardless and updating single aspx files on the fly is not recommended. If it's unavoidable, then restart will have happened eventually on any setup so it's worth using one of the below solutions anyway.

**Solutions**

**Compilation Mode**

Check the CompilationMode in your web.config. For more info check out this post
http://www.campusmvp.net/compilationmode-avoiding-aspx-page-compilation-to-improve-scalability-in-sites-with-thousands-of-pages/

This can be set on a server level too so you can get differences by environment.

**Session State Mode**

You can run your session state in StateServer mode or using Sql server. The ASP.NET state server will be sitting on your server if .net is installed and just needs to be set to auto start. You can then just switch it in the config.

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" useHostingIdentity="true" cookieless="false" timeout="120" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" />
```

We always run using the ASP.NET state server for development and in many cases in production.
I find when testing long user pathways (like a form wizard with many forms) it's very annoying to have session blatted every time you rebuild. That will also mean you don't lose session on app restarts.

You can also use SQL server in the same way.

NOTE: You must remember that if you are serialising classes into session state and you make changes, you will need to manually restart the state server or you'll get serialization errors. This is very rare, but just to be aware of in production environments.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue with the compilation mode. Obviously "Never" doesn't work. I tried "Auto", which let's me run for 2-3 requests after a change but then the Application ends without error (Server.GetLastError() is null) and Application_Error isn't firing. Setting the CompilationMode away from the default value(which hasn't changed between 4.0 and 4.5) doesn't do me any good.

Frustrating, I'd really like to know what caused the breaking change during the upgrade process.

Comment: See why this is happening. I'm 90% sure that's why there's a behavioural change when upgrading to 4.5. Previously it was one or the other between web pages and web applications.

Answer (score 0):

when using in-proc mode, your session data is hosted at server memory. You should verify on your IIS about application pool recycle time.

Cheers,

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but the apppool recycle time is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can try SQL server session state mode .

Comment: And what changed during the upgrade process?

Comment: you need to start state server windows service on server , also run some commands to install database that store session in sql server . for more information visit http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104082/Configuring-ASP-session-state-on-SQL-server in this session state mode your session will never expire .

Answer (score 0):

One maybe related issue: IIS (as well as ASP.NET Development Server) restarts the application after you **check-out a file** from TFS.

I have found the solution here: http://forums.iis.net/p/1200785/2055480.aspx/1?IIS+Express+restarts+site+when+a+file+is+checked+out

1. Navigate to: *%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0*
2. Delete the app_offline.htm file.
3. Create a folder named app_offline.htm