# Global.asax: session_end fire when page is loaded (Session variables lost)

Tags: html, asp.net

I am building a webapplication and have noticed some strange behaviour debugging this application. When the first page is loaded some session variables are being set. These session variables adopt the correct values (seen in debug mode) but if the page is done loading I noticed that the Global.asax session_end method is called. This ensures of course that the next page which expects these session variables fails.

I was wondering if visual studio or IIS (7.5 or higher) ends the session if visual studio has to rebuild/reload the page?

P.S.: The session_end method only gets called if a change in code has been made.

Comment: Please show us a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: found the answer on another page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101888/asp-net-inproc-session-restarted-after-markup-change-in-vs2012

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer on another page: [ASP.Net Inproc session restarted after markup change in VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13101888/asp-net-inproc-session-restarted-after-markup-change-in-vs2012) 
Hope this helps other people too.