# ASP.NET Web Forms: In development environment, engineers get logged out after making code changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies, forms-authentication

We have an ASP.NET Web Forms application which uses Forms Authentication.

In Visual Studio, unlike class library projects, if you make changes to the main website project (i.e. ASPX pages), you don't have to recompile your entire solution to test your results in the browser. You simply save your changes, and refresh the browser.

In our situation, after making a single change, we save and refresh the browser, and everything works fine. However, after 6th or 7th or 8th change, we get logged out. There is a long (5 min) delay of browser trying to refresh just to get back to the login screen.

I tried Googling, but not finding any relevant information. Does anyone know what can be causing this or point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13230002/3778318

Answer (score 1):

Your Sessions are more likely to be in "InProc" mode, so it means that your session variables are stored locally in the .NET worker process.

Ref: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webtopics/2009/07/21/in-proc-session-state-management/

Having this in mind, everytime you update a markup file (ASPX) .NET allows you to see changes without the need of recompiling the entire solution, it only precompiles the aspx which might be what is causing you session variables to dissapear.

You can find a more extensive answer to this here and how to avoid this behaviour: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13230002/3778318

Comment: You are correct, we are using InProc. It allows me to make markup file (ASPX) changes, it precompiles the aspx, and I can see the updated changes in my browser. The problem is, on the n-th markup file (ASPX) change, causes the session variable to disappear. The SO article you posted doesn't seem to offer any good solutions as one of the links there is broken. The accepted answer there doesn't apply to VS 2015 either. The other solution seems to be to use a StateServer or SQLServer to store the session, which doesn't seem to be good solutions for an issue that only happens to our developers.